# Past Continuous with for

Tags: british-english

I saw this sentence
For the past 2 months , animal trainer Mark Vette _____has been teaching___three dogs to drive.
Is it possible to say *was teaching* instead of  *has been teaching*.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Because it says "for the past 2 months", which means starting two months ago until now, the present perfect continuous is used. "For" and "since" are used this way, to express duration, which is still continuing or has very recently come to an end.

If you want to use "was teaching" you would have to change the sentence, for example: in May and June Mark Vette was teaching... But that is used to express that that was what he was doing during those two months, a temporary activity, which has now come to an end.